# How to dynamically change database in fastapi?

Tags: django, database, fastapi, asyncpg, tortoise-orm

there are different databases for different users. so after I extract the user from the api token, I want to switch my from my public database to the user database like how `THREAD_LOCAL.DB = dbname` works in django. I am currently using tortoise orm to manage the database connection. Is there a way to achieve that with tortoise or any other orm?

.

Comment: That depends on how you're retrieving the database connection in your code; that function should then return a connection from a pool reserved for that user (or switch the active database for that user if the underlying connection library supports it). You'll have to add some code that show how you currently manage your connections.

Comment: actually I am relatively new to fast api. I had this implemented on django server but decided to move it to fast api for async capabilities. So I haven't implemented it yet and couldn't find anything relevant. It would be great if you could suggest any way of approaching it.

Comment: You can start by looking at the `get_db` dependency in the examples in the official guide, and then adapt that to return a user specific session by depending on getting the current user: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#main-fastapi-app

Comment: Thank you for the helpful tips, I went through asyncpg documentation and got what I was looking for!

Comment: Great! Add your code as a self-answer with a reference to the documentation and accept it, so that it becomes a reference for any future people who come across this answer.